# Laggy presentation of SLServiceTypeFacebook

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, uiimagepickercontroller

so I'm making a post to Facebook and want the user to select an image before doing that.
Once the image is picked and I show Facebook. Problem is, when I show Facebook straight away, without the image picking part, it looks fine. When I show it after picking the image, Facebook sharing appears animated, but laggy. As if the action has a very low framerate or something.

Here's my code:

```
    self.portraitPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
    self.portraitPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
#endif
    [self.portraitPicker setDelegate:self];
    self.portraitPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:self.portraitPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now when this is complete, I show the Facebook posting modally:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
            {
                self.facebookController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
                [self.facebookController setInitialText:@"Some text"];
                [facebookController addImage:pickedImage];
                [self presentViewController:self.facebookController animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
        }];
```

I can do this in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` or the `imagePickerControllerDidCancel`, doesn't matter, the problem still comes up.

Being desperate, I tried:

> - Showing it on the main thread delayed
> - Showing it async
> - Showing it outside the dismiss-block
> - Showing it from the AppDelegate's rootviewcontroller instead

This is not Facebook-related as it happens with `SLServiceTypeTwitter` as well as with `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Can't seem to do away with the laggy animation that ONLY happens showing the image picker. Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Does it lag for the first presentation only, or every time u present it?

Comment: It lags every single time. 
It lags if I call it to be done in 5 seconds and I present and dismiss the image picker within those 5 seconds. But it doesn't lag if I don't present the image picker within those 5 seconds.

Starting to think it has something to do with my app hierarchy somehow, since I can't find a single other person mentioning this.

Comment: I think this is due to the animated:YES property, as it waits until one animation is finished and then the other starts, just give it a run with animated:NO.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. :-( In fact, I tried running the presentation a full few seconds after the last one finished too. No luck. 
But keep 'em coming, I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the lack of response and similar issues, I figured the cause was my own architecture.
It turns out that one of my viewcontrollers' ViewDidAppear was called after the camera picker was displayed (as it became the active viewcontroller and consequently the inactive one, giving control back to the original viewcontroller).

Blocking the background calls and animation that happened in this viewDidAppear resolved the issue. I still don't know why calling it delayed (i.e. 10 seconds, or even 100 seconds into the future, when nothing was going on) still had the laggy appearence show up, but there it is.